# UnboundLocalError Leetcode #5. Longest Palindromic Substring

Tags: python, unbound

Leetocode keeps giving me this UnboundLocalError, and I don't know why...

This is my code

```py
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        def isPalindrome(s):
            if len(s) == 1:
                return True
            if len(s) == 2 and s[0] == s[1]:
                return True
            else:
                if s[0] == s[-1]:
                    return isPalindrome(s[1:-1])
                else:
                    return False
        max_ = 0
        lenght = len(s)
        for i in range(lenght):
            for r in range(i + 1, lenght):
                if isPalindrome(s[i:r]):
                    len_ = r - i + 1
                    if len_ > max_:
                        max_ = len_
                        final = s[i:r]
        return final
```

and the error it gives me is

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'final' referenced before assignment
    return final
```

Can someone please help me understand why this may be occurring?

I think the problem may be given in the case where the final string is of len() = 1. In that case it might be a problem the s[i : r]

Answer (score 0):

your `final` variable is defined inside the `if` block and is not visible outside. just declare it outside to get rid of this erro

```py
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        def isPalindrome(s):
            if len(s) == 1:
                return True
            if len(s) == 2 and s[0] == s[1]:
                return True
            else:
                if s[0] == s[-1]:
                    return isPalindrome(s[1:-1])
                else:
                    return False
        max_ = 0
        lenght = len(s)

        final = 0 # declared final here

        for i in range(lenght):
            for r in range(i + 1, lenght):
                if isPalindrome(s[i:r]):
                    len_ = r - i + 1
                    if len_ > max_:
                        max_ = len_
                        final = s[i:r]
      

        return final
```

Answer (score 0):

Testcase in which `s` consist of only one letter. like ("a","d") your inner for loop is not executing and hence you define final inside the if is not initialize and you are returning `final` hence **unbound error** occurs.

> for ex. let's say s="s"
> Dry run-:
>
> max_  :0
>
> lenght    :1  (i.e len(s))
>
> for i in range(1):
>
> for j in **range(1,1)**    (i.e when first loop iterating i=0)  no inner loop run
>
> Exit()
>
> return Final #Unbound error

To solve this error you can initialize `final` outside. or you can add a condition `if len(s)==1: return 1`

also your code solution has time complexity **O(n^2)** I think it will show **Time limit exceeded.**